# How do I browse from the last record to 10 record before the last?

Tags: sql, vb.net, firebird, firebird2.5

Firebird connection to a database. How do I browse from the last record to 10th record before the last? Code below

```
Dim con As String = "User=SYSDBA;PASSWORD=masterkey;Database=/DATABASE/TIME_DBS/TC_SHPIRAG3ST4.gdb;Datasource=192.168.2.78;Port=3050;Dialect=3"
Dim conexiune As FbConnection = New FbConnection(con)
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    conexiune.Open()
    Try
        Dim sCmd As FbCommand
        Dim sql As String
        Dim ds As FbDataReader
        sql = "select * from RT_TIME ORDER BY RTTI_COUNTER desc"
        sCmd = New FbCommand()
        sCmd.Connection = conexiune
        sCmd.CommandText = sql
        ds = sCmd.ExecuteReader
        ds.Read()

        TextBox1.Text = ds("RTTI_BIT_POS")
        Label1.Text = ds("RTTI_HOOK_POS")

        ds.Close()
        conexiune.Close()
    Catch ex As FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString, vbCritical, "DB Error")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: nevermind, found it: sql = "select FIRST 1 SKIP 10 * from RT_TIME ORDER BY RTTI_COUNTER  desc "

Comment: Using `FIRST 1 SKIP 10` will give you the eleventh record from the end, not the last 10.

Answer (score 4):

To show the last 10 records, you need to apply a descending order to your query, and then only fetch the first 10 rows. Firebird supports several ways to do this:

SQL standard [`OFFSET/FETCH`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-dml-offsetfetch) (Firebird 3.0 and later):

```
select * 
from <table>
order by <column-list> desc
fetch first 10 rows only
```

Non-standard [`FIRST/SKIP`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-first-skip) (Firebird 1.0 and later):

```
select first 10 * 
from <table>
order by <column-list> desc
```

Non-standard [`ROWS`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-rows) (Firebird 2.0 and later):

```
select * 
from <table>
order by <column-list> desc
rows 10
```

With Firebird 2.5, you can use these last two options.